# Why are connections closing prematurely in our Spring/Hibernate/JDBC/Websphere system?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, websphere

We are having a sporatic issue with session closing during a users request with Spring+Hibernate+JDBC running on WAS8.  It has happened before and went away and now its reared its head again, always randomly.  I'm wanting to verify that it is not an application issue so that I can question our admins and be able to correctly say that it is not an application issue.  Also interested if anyone else has experienced this issue.

- Spring: 3.2.2
- Hibernate: 4.1.12
- Websphere: v8

To start, I'll list my assumptions. From my understanding, WAS handles connection pooling for datasources.  From those pools, hibernate/spring requests connection(s) creates its own logical connections by which it performs upon.  Then when it "closes" the connection/session it does not close the physical connection, but releases it back to the pool which handles when/if a connection should actually close.

All our transactions in the application use the @Transactional annotation and in some cases use readonly.  We `@Autowired` a `SessionFactory` into our DAO's super class and when getting a session we call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

Bean definition code:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource">
        <ref local="wasDataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="wasDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.WebSphereDataSourceAdapter">
    <property name="targetDataSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/HostDS" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="isolationLevel">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
            <property name="staticField">
                <value>java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <bean class="com.***.intranet.inp.model.AuditTrailInterceptor" />
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedPackages">
        <list>
            <value>com.***.intranet.inp.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.***.intranet.inp.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${db.schema}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="transactionAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

`hibernate.properties` file code:

```
hibernate.dialect = com.***.intranet.inp.hibernate.DB2ZosDialect<br>
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class = org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheRegionFactory<br>
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true<br>
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true<br>
hibernate.connection.pool_size = 30 (matches the datasource pool size)
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of when it errors because of closed connections? Also which FixPack of WAS8 are you running?

Comment: @TerrellPlotzki The admin console shows the app at ND 8.0.0.6 so I assume that means fixpack 8?  And in light of the length of the stack traces to follow just know I errored on the side of too much info rather than too little, :)

Comment: @TerrellPlotzki http://www.taplar.com/temp/stacktrace01.txt

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue involved something to do with a fixpack being applied to DB2 which was causing socket connection issues.  The DBAs rolled it back or found a fix for their fix, heh, and now the issue is not occuring any longer.

Not sure what to do now, as I'm new to stackoverflow.  Do I close the thread or something?  Dunno.